# JBOSS 7 - Osgi Bundles not present in JNDI TREE

Tags: jboss, osgi

I have a bundle in JBOSS7 Bundle Repository.

I want to lookup it from a WAR class throw JNDI, but in my JBOSS7.0.1.Final AS there is any trace of osgi in JNDI tree.

In JNDI tree I found only "java:" and "java:jboss", I think that when I deploy a bundle  the AS should add the "osgi:" leaf to the tree.
Why not?
Osgi Alliance specific says that when an osgi bundle is deployed it should be reachable throw JNDI...

Some ideas?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You are right, this part of the OSGi-JNDI spec is not yet done, you can track the progress here https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBOSGI-81

Note: there is a way to get this working, see here for more details: [Can't lookup OSGI services through JNDI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10483740/cant-lookup-osgi-services-through-jndi/10537978#10537978)