# Can't lookup OSGI services through JNDI

Tags: jboss, osgi, jndi

I'm working with JBossAS7.
My application has some OSGI modules and big non-OSGI part.
I tried lookup osgi services in non-osgi subsystem through JNDI but they are not present in JNDI context. 
I found similar problem at [JBOSS 7 - Osgi Bundles not present in JNDI TREE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7513242/jboss-7-osgi-bundles-not-present-in-jndi-tree) but I dont found any solution there. If JBoss team didn't implement this functionality yet, how can I resolve this problem now?

I tried adding my service to JNDI context manually but got an exception because JNDI context is read only(according to https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AS7-421)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not fully integrated yet (monitor [JBOSGI-81](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/jbosgi-81) to check the status), however I think you can make this work by taking the Apache Aries JNDI OSGi bundles and deploying them in JBoss AS7.

To do this, deploy and start

- The [Aries JNDI bundle](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/apache/aries/jndi/org.apache.aries.jndi/0.3.1/org.apache.aries.jndi-0.3.1.jar)
- The [Aries Proxy bundle](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/apache/aries/proxy/org.apache.aries.proxy/0.4/org.apache.aries.proxy-0.4.jar)
- The [Aries Util bundle](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/apache/aries/org.apache.aries.util/0.4/org.apache.aries.util-0.4.jar)

The JNDI bundle will complain that it can't set some statics with the NamingManager, but you can ignore that as AS7 JNDI takes care of that.
With the bundles above installed you should be able to do

```
osgi:service/org.foo.SomeInterface
```

and

```
osgi:servicelist
```

type lookups... E.g. you could try the following to look up the Start Level Service which is registered by the framework:

```
osgi:service/org.osgi.service.startlevel.StartLevel
```

I just tried it with AS7 7.1.2 and it works for me...

One thing to note, if the entity you're looking up implements an interface defined in another AS7/MSC module or OSGi bundle, you need to ensure that the consumer has visibility to it if you want to be able to cast to this interface. In the OSGi world you can just import the package, but in an AS7 module (e.g. a war file) you can achieve this by adding a *Dependencies* manifest header.

Comment: i added module to dependencies in manifest but got an exception
org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: Module [module_name]:main is not found in local module loader @19e3118a (roots: [jboss_directory]\modules)

Comment: It's unclear to me what your setup precisely is, and what dependency it complains about. Maybe you want to post your scenario in detail on the JBoss OSGi Forums [https://community.jboss.org/en/jbossosgi](https://community.jboss.org/en/jbossosgi). In the description above I've simply installed and started the Aries bundles. The module dependency relates to if you want to cast the object you looked up via JNDI to a particular api...

Comment: I can confirm this solution is working with 7.1.1.Final. Thank you!